# Redirect all subdirectories to the parent directory

Tags: nginx

Example case:

```
http://example.com/parent/any/subdirectorry/here
http://example.com/parent/random
http://example.com/parent/can/be/anything
```

I want all of the above to be showing the content of

```
http://example.com/parent/
```

If there is an index.htm file in the parent, for instance; when we visit the very first url we should be seeing that index.htm file (with properly loaded dependencies).

I have this which looks like it's working; but sadly it doens't allow the page to load any dependencies since it rewrites everything:

```
rewrite ^/parent/.+ /parent/index.html last;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably you need `try_files`?\

Comment: This is a terrible idea, you will have a lot of duplicated content.

Comment: @XavierLucas what do you mean

Comment: @Zettam You are rewritting basically everything that begins with `/parent/` to the same content. This means that this content (the index file content) will in other terms be accessible from a lot of different URLs. So you are doing **[content duplication](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en)** and your visibility on search engines will get crushed because such practices are very likely to be interpreted as an attempt to gather more traffic on your site with URL spamming towards irrelevant and immutable content.